# How to make screen appear when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, fft

```
# import library
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import librosa.display
import librosa
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft
from scipy import signal
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
from scipy.linalg import hankel
from acoustics.cepstrum import complex_cepstrum
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
# import GUI
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tksheet import Sheet
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox

# input sr
sr = 2000
ts = 1/sr
style.use('ggplot')

**# tkinter**  
main_win = tk.Tk()
main_win.title('program')
main_win.option_add('*font', ('Verdana', 15))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Mouse Event')

# mouse event
global mouse_click_no
global mouse_pos
mouse_pos = []
mouse_click_no = 0
mouse_data = []

frame = Frame(main_win)
frame.pack(pady=5)

label = Label(main_win)
label.pack()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# csv viewer
def open_file():
   global file_name
   file_name = fd.askopenfilename(title="Open a File",
                                 filetype=(("csv Files", "*.csv"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                                 initialdir=r'C:/Users/Ninebell/Desktop/test_data/')

   if file_name:
      try:
         filename = r"{}".format(file_name)
         df = pd.read_csv(filename)
      except ValueError:
         label.config(text="File could not be opened")
      except FileNotFoundError:
         label.config(text="File Not Found")
      disp_csv()

   # clear all the previous data in tree
   clear_treeview()
   tree.pack()

   # add new data in treeview widget
   tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
   tree["show"] = "headings"

   # for headings iterate over the columns
   for col in tree["column"]:
      tree.heading(col, text=col)

   # put data in rows
   df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
   for row in df_rows:
      tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

def clear_treeview():
   tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)

# display csv file
class disp_csv(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self)
      csv_title=file_name.split('/')[-1]
      self.title(csv_title)
      self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
      self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
      self.sheet = Sheet(
         self.frame,
         data=pd.read_csv(
            file_name,  # filepath here
         ).values.tolist(),
      )
      self.sheet.enable_bindings()
      self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
      self.sheet.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**# root tkinter**
def mouse_pos_update(rows):
    global mouse_data
    mouse_data = rows
    treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children())

    for i in rows:
        treeview.insert('', 'end', values=i)

def save_button():
    if len(treeview.get_children()) < 1:
        msgbox.showerror('No Data', 'No data available to export')
        return False

    file_path = fd.asksaveasfilename(title='Save CSV',
                                     filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")),
                                     initialdir=r'C:/Users/Ninebell/Desktop/test_data/')

    with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='') as myfile:
        exp_writer = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
        for i in treeview.get_children():
            row = treeview.item(i)['values']
            exp_writer.writerow(row)

    msgbox.showinfo('Message', 'Export sucessfully')


def load_csv():
    mouse_data.clear()
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open CSV',
                                  filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), ("All files", "*.*")),
                                  initialdir=r'C:/Users/Ninebell/Desktop/test_data/')
    with open(file_path) as myfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
        for i in csv_reader:
            mouse_data.append(i)
    mouse_pos_update(mouse_data)
    msgbox.showinfo('Data imported', 'Your data has be imported to' + os.path.basename(file_path) + 'sucessfully')

    txt_browse['text'] = file_path
    return None

def clear_button():
   treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children())
   for item in canvas.get_tk_widget().find_all():
       canvas.get_tk_widget().delete(item)


def root_quit():
    root.destroy()

# canvas.delete('all')
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# main_win GUI
menu = tk.Menu(main_win)
menu.config(font=('Verdana', 9))
comm_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
tbf_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
freq_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
over_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
hanm_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
spec_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
stft_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
wave_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
psd_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
mfcc_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
stab_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
ceps_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
sine_menu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

# telecommunications
comm_menu.add_command(label='Communication')
comm_menu.add_separator()
comm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Sensor Connection')
comm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Start')
comm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Stop')
comm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Save(csv)')
menu.add_cascade(label='Communication', menu=comm_menu)

# file menu
file_menu.add_command(label='Open File', command=open_file)
# file_menu.add_command(label='Read csv File', command=open_file)                 # csv 파일 읽기
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=quit)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)

# overall spectrum
over_menu.add_command(label='Overall Spectrum')
over_menu.add_separator()
over_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis')
over_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis')
over_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis')
menu.add_cascade(label='Overall', menu=over_menu)

# time base frequency menu
tbf_menu.add_command(label='Time Domain', command=disp_time)
tbf_menu.add_separator()
tbf_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_time)
tbf_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_time)
tbf_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_time)
menu.add_cascade(label='Time', menu=tbf_menu)

# frequency menu
freq_menu.add_command(label='Frequency', command=disp_freq)
freq_menu.add_separator()
freq_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_freq)
freq_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_freq)
freq_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_freq)
menu.add_cascade(label='Freq', menu=freq_menu)

# spectrogram 2d
spec_menu.add_command(label='2D Plot', command=disp_spec2d)
spec_menu.add_separator()
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_spec2d)
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_spec2d)
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_spec2d)
spec_menu.add_separator()

# spectrogram 3d
spec_menu.add_command(label='3D Plot', command=disp_spec3d)
spec_menu.add_separator()
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_spec3d)
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_spec3d)
spec_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_spec3d)
menu.add_cascade(label='Spectrogram', menu=spec_menu)

# cepstrum
ceps_menu.add_command(label='Cepstrum', command=disp_ceps)
ceps_menu.add_separator()
# cepstrum time
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time x-axis', command=x_ceps)
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time y-axis', command=y_ceps)
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time z-axis', command=z_ceps)
ceps_menu.add_separator()
# cepstrum frequency
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency x-axis')
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency y-axis')
ceps_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency z-axis')
menu.add_cascade(label='Cepstrum', menu=ceps_menu)

# hankel matrix
hanm_menu.add_command(label='Hankel Matrix', command=disp_hank)
hanm_menu.add_separator()
# hankel matrix time
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time x-axis', command=x_hank_t)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time y-axis', command=y_hank_t)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Time z-axis', command=z_hank_t)
hanm_menu.add_separator()
# hankel matrix frequency
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency x-axis', command=x_hank_f)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency y-axis', command=y_hank_f)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Frequency z-axis', command=z_hank_f)
hanm_menu.add_separator()
# hankel matrix spectrum
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Spectrum x-axis', command=x_hank_s)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Spectrum y-axis', command=y_hank_s)
hanm_menu.add_radiobutton(label='Spectrum z-axis', command=z_hank_s)
menu.add_cascade(label='Hankel', menu=hanm_menu)

# wavelet
wave_menu.add_command(label='Wavelet', command=disp_wave)
wave_menu.add_separator()
wave_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_wave)
wave_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_wave)
wave_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_wave)
menu.add_cascade(label='Wavelet', menu=wave_menu)

# STFT
stft_menu.add_command(label='STFT', command=disp_stft)
stft_menu.add_separator()
stft_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_stft)
stft_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_stft)
stft_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_stft)
menu.add_cascade(label='STFT', menu=stft_menu)

# MFCC
mfcc_menu.add_command(label='MFCC', command=disp_mfcc)
mfcc_menu.add_separator()
mfcc_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_mfcc)
mfcc_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_mfcc)
mfcc_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_mfcc)
menu.add_cascade(label='MFCC', menu=mfcc_menu)

# PSD
psd_menu.add_command(label='PSD', command=disp_psd)
psd_menu.add_separator()
psd_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_psd)
psd_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_psd)
psd_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_psd)
menu.add_cascade(label='PSD', menu=psd_menu)

# sine test
sine_menu.add_command(label='Sine Test', command=disp_sine)
sine_menu.add_separator()
sine_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis', command=x_sine)
sine_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis', command=y_sine)
sine_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis', command=z_sine)
menu.add_cascade(label='Sine Test', menu=sine_menu)

# stability
stab_menu.add_command(label='Stability')
stab_menu.add_separator()
stab_menu.add_radiobutton(label='x-axis')
stab_menu.add_radiobutton(label='y-axis')
stab_menu.add_radiobutton(label='z-axis')
menu.add_cascade(label='Stability', menu=stab_menu)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# root GUI
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

treeview = tk.ttk.Treeview(frame,
                           columns=['one', 'two', 'three'],
                           displaycolumns=['one', 'two', 'three'],
                           show='headings',
                           height=10)
treeview.pack(fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

treeview.column('#1', width=150, anchor='center')
treeview.heading('one', text='index', anchor='center')

treeview.column('#2', width=150, anchor='center')
treeview.heading('two', text='Frequency[Hz]', anchor='center')

treeview.column('#3', width=150, anchor='center')
treeview.heading('three', text='Amplitude[mV/g]', anchor='center')

# browse
browse_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Open File Dialog')
browse_frame.pack(fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

txt_browse = Label(browse_frame, text='No File Selected', font=('Verdana', 9, 'bold'))
txt_browse.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

# button
button_frame = Frame(root) # bg='white'
button_frame.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_exit = Button(button_frame, text='Exit', width=12, command=root_quit)
btn_exit.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_del = Button(button_frame, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_button)
btn_del.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_save = Button(button_frame, text='Save', width=12, command=save_button)
btn_save.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_load = Button(button_frame, text='Load', width=12, command=load_csv)
btn_load.pack(side='right', padx=5, pady=5)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GUI
root.config(menu=menu)
main_win.config(menu=menu)
main_win.geometry('800x500')
main_win.resizable(False, False)
main_win.mainloop()
```

This displays a graph for each signal when a file is selected. Among them, FFT is set to display the coordinate values in the tree view.

I want the FFT screen to appear when the button is pressed, but don't know how.

Comment: If you trim your code down to isolate the specific problem you have you are much more likely to get help.  Please try to trim your code and include only the relevant information and  `imports`. I would think this should be straight forward.  If you want your button to display specific information after being pressed then create a function with the specific information you want displayed and pass the function to your command argument like you have done with your other buttons.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

for background image  in tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
canv = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
image = PhotoImage(file="./logo.png")
canv.create_image(100, 100, image=image)
canv.grid(row=0, column=1)
```